# Finding which drives are connected to computer

Tags: batch-file

I have a small side project I've been working on and i want to add an option to scan the computer and find which drives are connected and what they are(USB, Hard drive, Disc drive, SSD, etc.)

this is what i have so far.

```
echo off
:start
color 0a
cls
title Search
echo To search enter the drive and term you wish to search below.
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
set inputdrive=
set /p inputdrive=Drive:
set input=
set /p input=Search:
dir %inputdrive%:\%input% /s /b
pause
echo search again?
set inputsearch=
set /p inputsearch=(Y/N)
if %inputsearch%==Y goto start
if %inputsearch%==N exit
```

I plan on adding an option to scan for connected drives at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WMIC to get the info without the need for administrator rights.

Here is code that gives a nice listing of all available drives, including removable media drives that do not have any media installed:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set ^"driveTypes=^
0Unknown          :^
1No Root Directory:^
2Removable Media  :^
3Local Disk       :^
4Network Drive    :^
5CD/DVD           :^
6RAM Disk         :^"

echo Available Drives:
echo(
echo ID  Drive Type         Volume Name
echo --  -----------------  -----------
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%A in (
  '"wmic logicalDisk get DeviceID, DriveType, VolumeName"'
) do if "%%B" neq "" (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=:" %%D in ("!driveTypes:*%%B=!") do (
    endlocal
    echo %%A  %%D  %%C
  )
)
```

Just a bit more code will restrict the list to only drives that are available with media:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set ^"driveTypes=^
0Unknown          :^
1No Root Directory:^
2Removable Media  :^
3Local Disk       :^
4Network Drive    :^
5CD/DVD           :^
6RAM Disk         :^"

echo Available Drives:
echo(
echo ID  Drive Type         Volume Name
echo --  -----------------  -----------
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%A in (
  '"wmic logicalDisk get DeviceID, DriveType, VolumeName"'
) do if "%%B" neq "" dir %%A >nul 2>nul && (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=:" %%D in ("!driveTypes:*%%B=!") do (
    endlocal
    echo %%A  %%D  %%C
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! i think this should work great for what i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
fsutil fsinfo drives
fsutil fsinfo drivetype c:
```

But you need to have administrator rights to use it